# How to do a MYSQL query with an array in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

How can I query a database using the results of a prior query if they are in array? Below is what I have thus far.

```
$query = "SELECT * from searchtestdb where engname in ( SELECT synonyms.synonym  FROM words  LEFT JOIN synonyms ON synonyms.word_id = words.word_id WHERE word LIKE '%$searchBox%') ";

while($result = mysql_fetch_array($query)) 
        {
            echo $result['engname'];
            echo "<br> ";
            echo "<br> ";
        }
```

How can I get the $result['engname'] and query again? I'm thinking something like

```
SELECT * from searchtestdb where engname LIKE '%$result['engname']%';
```

but that obviously doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Why would you want to query the same table again to get the same row? Are you going to use $result['engname'] and find rows that engGame is similar (hence the like) or do you want to find the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while($result = mysql_fetch_array($query)) 
{
   $query2 = "SELECT * from searchtestdb where engname LIKE '%".$result['engname']."%';";
   $result2 = mysql_query($query2);
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) 
   {
       echo $row["somthing"];
   }
}
```

Comment: good answer but i think some more explanation about concating strings is in order: For more info read this: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php